# selecting cases based upon first few characters in spss?

Tags: select, spss

i want to select cases with particular first 3 characters.

for example cases with first 3 characters containing `"I22"`.

the length of whole value can vary. e,g `"I228"` or `"I2279"` but they have common first three characters `"I22"`

i usually use `compute variable_name= "I228".`

but this is tedious as i have to enter all variation of `"I22"` e.g `"I228"`, `"I229"` and so on..

it would be much easier if i can just select cases based upon same first 3 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `char.cubstr` function to find out what the first three characters are in your string variable. For example:

```
if char.substr(variable_name,1,3)="I22" keep_this=1.
```

or:

```
select cases if char.substr(variable_name,1,3)="I22".
```